# Communication between two fragments using activity gives NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-volley

I have an activity which loads a fragment `cpt_loader` as soon as the `bookings` button is clicked. `cpt_loader` shows a circular progress bar until the data is fetched from a `MySQL database` using `Volley library`. As soon as the response is received, `cpt_loader` sends JSONObject to `MainActivity` using an interface. It works perfectly until this point and the data is also received in `MainActivity`. But, when I send the JSONObject again from `MainActivity` to `bookings` fragment using interface, I get:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.user.temporary.MainActivity$sendCPTToBookings.sendToBookings(org.json.JSONObject)' on a null object reference`

Code in MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.user.temporary;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        cpt_loader.sendCPTToMainActivity {
    sendCPTToBookings sendListener;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LinearLayout profilebtn = (LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.profile_button);
        LinearLayout bookingsbtn = (LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.bookings_button);
        LinearLayout gamesbtn = (LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.games_button);
        bookingsbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cpt_loader loader_frame = new cpt_loader();
                FragmentTransaction trans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                trans.replace(R.id.fragment_frame, loader_frame);
                trans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                trans.commit();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void sendCPT(JSONObject cpt_json){
        sendListener.sendToBookings(cpt_json);

    }

    public interface sendCPTToBookings {
        void sendToBookings(JSONObject cpt_json);
    }
}
```

Code in cpt_loader.java:

```
package com.example.user.temporary;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class cpt_loader extends Fragment {
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    final String dataUrl = "http://10.0.2.2/futsal/main.php";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    private sendCPTToMainActivity mListener;

    public cpt_loader() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static cpt_loader newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        cpt_loader fragment = new cpt_loader();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cpt_loader, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final ArrayList<String> cities_array = new ArrayList<String>();
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        final RelativeLayout ld = (RelativeLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.loader);
        final RelativeLayout fb = (RelativeLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.form_body);
        final Spinner city_sp = (Spinner)getView().findViewById(R.id.city_sp);
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, dataUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try{
                    bookings bookings_frame = new bookings();
                    FragmentTransaction trans = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    trans.replace(R.id.fragment_frame, bookings_frame);
                    trans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                    trans.commit();
                    mListener.sendCPT(response);
                } catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }

    public void onButtonPressed(JSONObject json) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.sendCPT(json);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof sendCPTToMainActivity) {
            mListener = (sendCPTToMainActivity) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface sendCPTToMainActivity {
        void sendCPT(JSONObject cpt_json);
    }
}
```

Code in bookings.java:

```
package com.example.user.temporary;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class bookings extends Fragment implements MainActivity.sendCPTToBookings{
    private long L1;
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    public bookings() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static bookings newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        bookings fragment = new bookings();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bookings, container, false);
        return v;

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();

    }

    public void sendToBookings(JSONObject json_obj){
        try{
            JSONArray cities = json_obj.getJSONArray("city");
            int num_cities = cities.length();
            for(int i=0;i<num_cities;i++) {
                System.out.println(cities.getString(i));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Also, in the official android documentation in this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html), the data is passed from fragment to the activity, but in contrary to my application, the activity directly processes the views in the second fragment. I don't know if an activity is capable of sending data to the fragment using interfaces.

Comment: I can't see where do you instantiate sendListener variable

Comment: First line of MainActivity class :-)

Comment: that is not *instantiation*, it is *declaration*. Instantiation means `sendListener = ...`. You never assign the value to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: That is empty, you would need to put the fragment in there at some point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work this way. Here is 2 problem:

1. You didn't initialize `sendListener` in MainActivity
2. If you initialize `sendListener` from `bookings` Fragment it may not work all time. Because there is no guarantee that  `bookings` will be initialized and attached to `MainActivity` before your call `mListener.sendCPT(response);`. And if `bookings` Fragment is not created and  attached before calling `mListener.sendCPT(response);`,  your `sendListener` will be null. `sendListener` will be valid after `bookings` Fragment created and attached to Activity.

You can do it other way. You can save the `JSONObject` in `MainActivity`. And when  `bookings` Fragment is attached to MainActivity you can just call a MainActivity method `getMeJson()` From `bookings` Fragment. And check if is null or valid.

**MainActivity**

```
JSONObject  jsonObject;

@Override
public void sendCPT(JSONObject cpt_json){
    jsonObject = cpt_json;
}
public JSONObject getMeJson(){
  return jsonObject;
}
```

**bookings Fragment**

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof MainActivity) {
        MainActivity activity = (MainActivity)context;
        JSONObject jsonObject = activity.getMeJson():
    }

}
```

Comment: It works now. And is that the standard approach for sending data from one fragment to the other?

Comment: You can send data from one `Fragment` to another `Fragment` via `Bundle`

Answer (score 0):

I've found that sending data TO Fragments is easier with a setter or other function than an interface.

```
Fragment targetFragment = GetFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("targetFragment ");
if(targetFragment != null){
  ((MyFragmentClass) targetFragment).receiveData(data);
}
```